# How to suppress USB disconnect system message when using a KVM switch with linux

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I use a KVM switch to switch back and forth between a rasberry pi and an Acer notebook running Rocky Linux in console mode so that they can share a keyboard and mouse. Whenever I switch back and forth the Pi does not complain but the Rocky laptop flashes a rush of messages across the terminal such as:

```
USB disconnect, device number 12,
USB disconnect, device number 13,
New USB device found
New USB device strings
```

Both devices continue to disconnect and reconnect so at least for now I am not too concerned. However the flood of messages on the Rocky Linux machine is disruptive. Is there any way I can suppress them so that they do not show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reconnections are normal. I think it's the cheapest way to build a KVM – it literally switches the input USB ports from one output to another.

You can make the messages not show up *on the console,* by reducing the "console log level":

```
dmesg --console-level=notice
```

I think the default is 'info'. If this isn't quite enough, lower it further to 'warn'. Note that the messages will still show up in `dmesg` regardless, they just won't be copied to console directly.

This corresponds to the `loglevel=` kernel option (loglevel=4 is notice, loglevel=5 is warn).

Comment: thank you very much! This worked like charm.